# Clausula CASE optimizada

Tags: sql-server

Tengo que hacer una consulta similar a

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN 
    (SELECT MAX(Fecha) FROM Tabla) > '01/01/1900' THEN (SELECT MAX(Fecha) FROM Tabla) 
    ELSE '01/01/1900' END
```

El problema es que se esta ejecutando dos veces el  `(SELECT MAX(Fecha) FROM Tabla)`. Una para evaluar el dato y otra para mostrarlo.

La consulta (esto es solo un ejemplo) la tengo dentro de una función que devuelve una tabla y en ellas no puedo declarar variables.

¿Hay alguna forma de evitar esto sin tener que usar una función escalar?

Comment: Por que no puedes declara variables en la función?

Answer (score 4):

En el entendido de que tu consulta es de ejemplo y solo funciona para un valor, para el caso de una consulta de múltiples registros podrías hacer una subconsulta.

```
SELECT Inf.Campo, CASE
              WHEN Inf.Fecha > '01/01/1900' THEN Inf.Fecha 
              ELSE '01/01/1900'
           END
FROM (
     SELECT CampoAgrupador AS Campo, MAX(Fecha)
     FROM dbo.fnDatos()
     GROUP BY CampoAgrupador
) AS Inf
```

El Campo agrupador depende los datos que contenga el resultado de tu función y lo que ocupes agrupar.

Comment: De hecho, funcionaría para uno o más registros en la tabla, creo que se adapta perfecto a lo que desea el OP. Buena respuesta!